# How can I rename a USB sound device (headphone) in Windows Sound settings?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, usb, audio, drivers

How can I rename the CORSAIR HS70 device, I want to get rid of the prefix "2-". I have searched the registry and replaced all strings alike, but the "2-" seems to come back. After changing the registry I made sure the strings with "2-" are all replaced by searching again.

Via properties I can rename the 1st line saying "Headset Earphone CORSAIR", but NOT the line below "2-CORSAIR ...". Some programs rely on the driver name (2nd line), that is why I want to change it. The "2" came up when I had to change the USB port.

[image: Prefix Sound device]

Here for instance the name seems to be restored with "2-" after a restart.

[image: Registry]

In the device manager it has no "2-".

[image: Device manager]

Comment: As it's a USB device, maybe [Rename devices in Device Manager](https://superuser.com/q/437755/272824) will help.

Comment: Good point, but no luck. Updated question. I am also not sure where the names in the device manager come from, probably also from the registry.

Comment: `In the device manager it has no "-2".` ... it's `2-` ... please correct your post

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? My OCD is killing me lol

Comment: Reinstalled - completely removed the device and all leftovers in all places and then reinstalled again. This was the only thing helped for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to remove not only the obvious audio device(s) but also the parent controller device in the Device Manager. It also helps to show hidden devices when doing this.

1. Open Device Manager.
2. Open the View menu and select `Show hidden devices`.
3. Uninstall the desired audio devices listed under `Audio inputs and outputs`.
   For example: **Speakers (2 - Realtek High Definition Audio(SST))**.
4. Uninstall the relevant controller device listed under `Sound, video and game controllers`.
   Note that the device doesn't have the prefix here, but uninstall it anyway.
   For example: **Realtek High Definition Audio(SST)**.
5. Open the Action menu and select `Scan for hardware changes`.

The devices should then reinstalled without the prefix.

If you change which USB port the device is plugged into, it's possible that the issue might come back again.

Answer (score 2):

You can view all audio devices using the below registry key:

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render

Key: {device-sid}\Properties
Name: {b3f8fa53-0004-438e-9003-51a46e139bfc},6
REG_SZ: Name of device (e.g. Logitech PRO X Wireless Gaming Headset)

You'd need to find the values you would like to change and make the amendments, from testing previously this shouldn't need a reboot to be visible so possibly a login script via GPO would do the trick.
This solved the issue for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the device, select Properties, and then rename the device.

Works here on several machines: Windows 10 and Windows 11.

This works for installed Devices.

USB devices are not (strictly speaking) installed devices, so you may not be able to rename them.

Comment: Yes this works, but it renames the 1st line saying "Headset Earphone CORSAIR", but NOT the line below. I will update this detail in the question.

Comment: There is more than one registry location (current versions ) so maybe that is the reason.

Comment: I have searched and changed all of them (about 5-6), restart, but it tends to come back.

Comment: The issue is possibly because the device is a USB device which can change ports .  For installed devices, my answer is accurate.  Renaming in Device Manager does not seem to work

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to open Settings.
2. Click "System"
3. Click "Sound"
4. Click "Device properties" in the Output section.
5. Type a new name, and click "Rename".

[image: Sound settings screenshot]
[image: rename screen]

Answer (score 0):

One way which seems to work - at least in my particular case - is to UNINSTALL the driver (I did this from the Device Manager). After a reboot it was automatically installed again, now without prefix "2-"